# Что значит listen в nginx?

Tags: nginx

Всем привет.
У меня обычный VDS на Ubuntu на Nginx+Apache.

Как я понимаю.
Так должно быть в любом конфиге nginx.

> server {   listen: айпишник сервера на котором установлен nginx: порт
>   80 }

На своем сервере обнаружил такую шнягу:

> server {   listen: айпишник НЕПОНЯТНОГО САЙТА: порт 80 }

Причем это непонятный сайт торгует спортивным питанием для качков.
Подскажите. Как такое могло случится? Это какой то вирус? Или взломали прописали.

Comment: Может, когда-то давно у вашего сервера был другой айпишник или этот конфиг когда-то давно перенесли с другого сервера не глядя?

Comment: Скорее, старое что-то. Дальше-то что, куда root указывает, на какую папку? Чужой сайт не будут же хранить на вашем сервере.

Comment: Да и вообще, если ip чужой, то как эти пакеты на ваш сервер попадут?)